# How to set payout threshold and Rigname in ethminer?

Tags: ether, mining, wallets, mining-pools, ethminer

I'm new to ethminer. I was just following the simple guides in [ethermine.org](https://ethermine.org). It says to start ethminer, we have to create a bat with the following contents, which I did:

```
setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
ethminer.exe --farm-recheck 200 -G -S eu1.ethermine.org:4444 -FS us1.ethermine.org:4444 -O <Your_Ethereum_Address>.<RigName>
```

Now a few questions:

1- How to set the payout threshold? So whenever the mined amount reached that, it automatically sends it to my wallet address?

2- What is that Rigname?

3- For the address, that is my wallet address, right? e.g. my Binance ETH deposit address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- How to set the payout threshold? So whenever the mined amount reached that, it automatically sends it to my wallet address?
*You would have to set this up in your pool, if you go to ethermine help there will be some information there, pools usually make this very hard to find!*

2- What is that Rigname?
*Rigname can be anything you want to identify your rig*

3- For the address, that is my wallet address, right? e.g. my Binance ETH deposit address.
*yes this is your wallet address, although i would use myetherwallet and download a paper wallet and use that instead of an online exchange wallet.
hope this helps*